# How to make the response-mode wrap text in proof general

Tags: hooks, proof-general

I'm using proof general and I would like to have the response window wrap text. The default display is a three-window mode. The buffers are called `proof-script-buffer` `proof-goals-buffer` and `proof-response-buffer` ([documentation](https://proofgeneral.github.io/doc/master/adaptingman/Internals-of-Proof-General/)). The first two wrap text as expected, but the response buffer does not. I tried adding this line to my `.emacs` file:

```
(add-hook 'proof-response-hook #'visual-line-mode)
```

but it did not have an effect. I can type `M-x visual-line-mode` inside of the response buffer, which works, but I have to type this every time I start emacs.

Comment: Is that hook invoked after the response buffer has its content? Sounds like you maybe need to put that function on a different hook. You can try `M-x debug-on-entry visual-line-mode` to see what happens when it's invoked in this context, e.g. to see if the buffer has content.